# JSON Parsing problem

Tags: java, json

Hey,
Im trying to parse the following JSON data:

```
{"chat":
{"link":
[{"@rel":"next","@ref":"http"}],
"events":
{"link2":
[{"@rel":"next","@ref":"http"}]}
}}
```

The code that reads the data is (where 'a' is the JSON as String):

```
  JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(a);
  JSONObject jsonObject = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("chat");
```

So the structure (at least the way I intended) is:

```
<chat>
    <link>
    <events>
        <link2>
    </events>
</chat<
```

But, after getJsonObject("chat"), jsonObject equals to:

```
{"chat":{"events":{"link2":[{"@ref":"http","@rel":"next"}]},"link":[{"@ref":"http","@rel":"next"}]}}
```

What am I missing? Why does the data flips and the structure changes?

Comment: *"Why does the data flips and the structure changes?"* I don't see any structure changes, just "data flips" (e.g., changes in the order in which the properties are shown). As msalvadores points out below, there is no order to the properties in an object represented by JSON. (From [the JSON site](http://json.org): *"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"*) To have order, you must use an ordering construct (such as an array). Since the only arrays in your structure only have one element, it's not evident from the above, but array entries are ordered and so won't be moved around.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, you should make this an answer.

Comment: @Lucero: Well, it's mostly just an extension of msalvadores' answer, which is why I commented rather than answering. Really, what I should have done / should do is *edit* msalvadores' answer to add the link and quote or something, as StackOverflow is meant to be collaborative. But I'm really cautious about doing that (and most people seem to be, probably more cautious than Jeff originally planned). **Edit:** And I've done that now, we should all be more willing to make good answers even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties in a JSON object are not sorted. From [the JSON site](http://json.org):

> An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs...

*(My emphasis)* Therefore the position of `link` and `event` are irrelevant for the parser. Bottom line, `link` and `event` are at the same level therefore they can be shifted and wherever order matters use arrays in JSON ... `[]`.